# How to publish leaderboard on Google Plus from Google Play Games lib in Android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm developing an application that uses Google Play Games Leaderboard and BaseGameUtils. The thing is that I want to publish the leaderboard on user's Google Plus and I can't find any exmaple showing how can I do that.

Can that be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see this tutorial.
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to use the Google Play services SDK. Besides, you will need to create a Leaderboard in your developer's console. You obtain a unique ID from there that need to associate your game and the leader board. 
This tutorial is slightly outdated, but it should give you an idea - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-game-services-leaderboards--cms-20700